# Is it possible to change a tkinter application's theme based on Windows 10's current light/dark theme configuration?

Tags: python, tkinter, windows-10

How could I make a tkinter application capable of automatically changing its colour scheme to a dark one when the user changes Windows 10 colour app mode from Light to Dark and viceversa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `root.after` to check for changes in registry.

```
from winreg import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(background="white")
label = tk.Label(root,text="Light mode on")
label.pack()

def monitor_changes():
    registry = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    key = OpenKey(registry, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize')
    mode = QueryValueEx(key, "AppsUseLightTheme")
    root.config(bg="white" if mode[0] else "black")
    label.config(text="Light Mode on" if mode[0] else "Dark Mode on",
                 bg="white" if mode[0] else "black",
                 fg="black" if mode[0] else "white")
    root.after(100,monitor_changes)

monitor_changes()

root.mainloop()
```

For completeness, here is how you configure a `ttk.Style` object to change the theme:

```
root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("BW.TLabel",foreground="black",background="white")
label = ttk.Label(root,text="Something",style="BW.TLabel")
label.pack()

def monitor_changes():
    ...
    style.configure("BW.TLabel",foreground="black" if mode[0] else "white", background="white" if mode[0] else "black")
    ...
```

Comment: Doesn't answer question…

Comment: Can you clarify which part you think is missing?

Comment: In first sentence: "...make a tkinter application capable of automatically changing its colour scheme...". Just changing a single `Label` isn't quite the same thing, IMO.

Comment: Oh ok. I interpreted his question as how to get windows theme mode rather than tkinter as there are already answers on SO regarding to themes changing.

Comment: Your answer may still be useful in regards as to how to determine the current theme or detect that it has changed. The only "theming" I'm aware of in tkinter is that for [`ttk` themed widgets](https://web.archive.org/web/20190315202103id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk.html).

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I wanted, sorry if my wording was confusing :)